# How do I run a PCA on TCGA data in r?

Tags: r, pca

I am trying to run a PCA on my TCGA data using TCGAvisualize_PCA. Here is my code:

```
# TCGAbiolinks Downloads
library(SummarizedExperiment)
library(TCGAbiolinks)

# GDCquery: searches the genomic data commons for the given project and category, filtering results as needed and returning an object with a summary table
query.gbmexp <- GDCquery(project = "TCGA-GBM",
                  data.category = "Transcriptome Profiling",
                  access = "open",
                  legacy = FALSE,
                  experimental.strategy = "RNA-Seq",
                  workflow.type = "HTSeq - Counts")

# Downloading data
GDCdownload(query = query.gbmexp, method = "api")

# Bringing data into environment
data <- GDCprepare(query = query.gbmexp, save = TRUE, 
                   save.filename = "TCGA_GBM_GeneExpression.rda",
                   summarizedExperiment = TRUE)

# data prep
GBMPrep <- TCGAanalyze_Preprocessing(data)

# normalization
normdata <- TCGAanalyze_Normalization(tabDF = GBMPrep, geneInfo, method = "geneInfoHT")

# filtering
GBMDataFilt <- TCGAanalyze_Filtering(tabDF = normdata,
                                  method = "varFilter")

# PCA 
group1 <- TCGAquery_SampleTypes(colnames(GBMDataFilt), typesample = c("NT"))
group2 <- TCGAquery_SampleTypes(colnames(GBMDataFilt), typesample = c("TP"))
pca <- TCGAvisualize_PCA(GBMDataFilt, dataDEGsFiltLevel, ntopgenes = 200, group1, group2)
```

My PCA code returns this error:

Error in names(sampleColors) <- colnames(expr2) :
'names' attribute [174] must be the same length as the vector [161]

And for reference, this is the example listed in the help page for TCGAvisualize_PCA:

```
# normalization of genes
dataNorm <- TCGAbiolinks::TCGAanalyze_Normalization(tabDF = dataBRCA, geneInfo = geneInfo,
method = "geneLength")
# quantile filter of genes
dataFilt <- TCGAanalyze_Filtering(tabDF = dataBRCA, method = "quantile", qnt.cut =  0.25)
# Principal Component Analysis plot for ntop selected DEGs
    # selection of normal samples "NT"
    group1 <- TCGAquery_SampleTypes(colnames(dataFilt), typesample = c("NT"))
    # selection of normal samples "TP"
    group2 <- TCGAquery_SampleTypes(colnames(dataFilt), typesample = c("TP"))
pca <- TCGAvisualize_PCA(dataFilt,dataDEGsFiltLevel, ntopgenes = 200, group1, group2)
```

I realize that I did a few things differently, such as using the "geneInfoHT" method for normalization and the "varFilter" method for data filtering, so could that be the source of my error?

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Does the example work? Check the `length(group1)`, `length(group2)` and `ncol(GBMDataFilt@assays[[1]])`

Comment: @csgroen the example does work, but as soon as I change tabDF to my data it throws an error. There is a difference in length where my group1 is of length 5 and 2 is 156, and when I attempt the ncol function I get the error "Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'ncol': trying to get slot "assays" from an object of a basic class ("matrix") with no slots"

Comment: Ah, it's a matrix, it's even easier. Try `ncol(GBMDataFilt)`. If it's 174, the issue is that you have samples that are not classified as either `NT` or `TP` and you should remove them from the matrix.